# Change Div Position on Window Resize

Tags: jquery, css

When I resize my browser window the following code isn't being activated. Only on page load the **else if** statement work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(updateBoxDimension);
$(document).ready(updateBoxDimension);
$(window).on('resize', updateBoxDimension);

function updateBoxDimension() {
    var $box = $('.case-study-outer');

    // To center the box
    var boxTop = ($(window).height()) / 2 - ($box.height() / 2);

    if ($(window).width() < 900) {
        $box.css({
            top: inherit
        });
    } else if ($(window).width() > 900) {
        $box.css({
            top: boxTop
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside --- if you want to center the element, why not use just CSS ?

Comment: You should really use CSS for this

Comment: Why making it so complicated. Just use CSS and its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out flex boxes, they might be exactly what you need. Here is a useful link on how to use them, they are used within CSS. 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yep - that is a solution but not all browsers support this yet.